# Google Data Studio Table Heatmap for Negative values

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I'm looking to have heatmap in google data studio to work with negative and positive values. Can there be two different color schemes for negative and positive values?

Currently, my column looks like this:

[image]

Style settings:

[image]

I want to highlight the negative values too (for example, red color scheme).

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using [Conditional Formatting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9528890); for example (where `Score` represents the respective field):

### 1) Red (Negative Values)

- ***Colour Type***: Single Colour
- ***Format Rues***: `Score` Less Than 0
- ***Colour and Style***: `Score` field with a Red Background Colour

[image]

### 2) Green (Positive Values)

- ***Colour Type***: Single Colour
- ***Format Rues***: `Score` Greater Than or Equal to 0
- ***Colour and Style***: `Score` field with a Green Background Colour

[image]

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/efc3166e-52e6-4789-ae52-9018b9f87949) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Comment: To me this solution works, and you can even choose "Gradient". Which, as Boxbot noted, require you to specify absolute min and max. But, you can also use percentage, which may work most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Not as a colour scale, no. Nimantha's solution will work if you only need binary colours for positive and negative, but if you want a positive gradient and negative gradient, you'd need to enter the min and max values for each column as a conditional format.

Data Studio doesn't currently have a way to sub in min and max variables for a range, so that means manual entry for every column (and even then, it won't have full functionality when date ranges are adjusted). Bit of a pain that they haven't implemented something so straightforward.